# How to bind colour to change the colour of a button in different conditions?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm currently trying to make a button which in certain conditions, will be grayed off. Just putting the colour hex code in xaml the button will display with the correct colour. But after binding it, even with the condition satisfied, the button will not appear at all. Any fixes?

XAML:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Frame HasShadow="False">
                        <Frame.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="{Binding Color1}" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="{Binding Color2}" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Frame.Background>
                    </Frame>
                    <StackLayout Padding="5,5,5,5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding PrintTap}" />
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Image Source="icbtn_print" />
                        <Label
                            Text="Print DO"
                            TextColor="#111111"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
```

C#:

```
    public string color1; 
    public string Color1
    {
        get
        {
            return color1;
        }
        set
        {
            color1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Color1));
        }
    }
    public string color2;
    public string Color2
    {
        get
        {
            return color2;
        }
        set
        {
            color2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Color2));
        }
    }
        if (SOHeader.status == "SYNC TO JDE ")
        {
            Color1 = "#FFFFFF";
            Color2 = "#C1C1C1";
        }
        else
        {
            Color1 = "#808080";
            Color2 = "#808080";
        }
```

Comment: Check this [related issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12339)

Answer (score 1):

You need to propagate BindingContext to GradientBrush to bind normally,

Here is my xaml code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Name="root"
         x:Class="App5.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Frame HasShadow="False">
                <Frame.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" BindingContext ="{Binding Path=BindingContext,Source={x:Reference root}}">
                        <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="{Binding Color1}" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="{Binding Color2}" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Frame.Background>
            </Frame>
            <StackLayout Padding="5,5,5,5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="icbtn_print" />
                <Label
                       Text="Print DO"
                       TextColor="#111111"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is my cs code:

```
    public string Color1 { get; set; }
    public string Color2 { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Color1 = "#f00";
        Color2 = "#00f";
        BindingContext = this;
    }
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the bindable property 'Color' is not compatible with an object of type string?